# How to replace .NET configuration source at runtime

Tags: .net, configuration

Here is my problem. I have a `system.serviceModel` group, where the services and client sections are out-sourced using the `configSource` facility. Now I have two distinct sets of out-sourced services/client files - one set for the non secure communication and the other - for the secure one.

I wish to run the server with a command line switch,like /cfgSource=Secure or /cfgSource=NonSecure (or /cfgSource=kuku, provided there are services/client configuration files corresponding to kuku), which will effectively switch the configuration to secure or non secure mode.

This is the big picture. Now the details. My `system.serviceModel` group currently looks like so:
[image]

Where the `bindings` and `behaviors` sections define all the bindings and behaviors needed by both the secure and non secure `services` and `client` configurations. Now I wish to run the application with the command line switch `/cfgSource=A.Plain`, which would change the lines

```
<services configSource="Cfg\A.Secure\services.config" />
<client configSource="Cfg\A.Secure\client.config" />
```

to

```
<services configSource="Cfg\A.Plain\services.config" />
<client configSource="Cfg\A.Plain\client.config" />
```

So, I have happily proceeded to change the configuration, like so:

```
var cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var serviceModel = (ServiceModelSectionGroup)cfg.GetSectionGroup("system.serviceModel");
serviceModel.Sections["services"].SectionInformation.ConfigSource = @"Cfg\A.Plain\services.config";
serviceModel.Sections["client"].SectionInformation.ConfigSource = @"Cfg\A.Plain\client.config";
cfg.Save();
```

Gevalt! Not only the configSource references are changed (which is fine), but the actual files under A.Plain are overwritten with those under A.Secure! I understand, that this is quite logical, but what should I do to keep the A.Plain files intact and just replace the configSource references?

Thanks a lot in advance to all the good Samaritans out there.

P.S.

I am interested in configuration based solutions. I know that I could change the files using XPATH and then run the application code in a new app domain. This solution is my last resort and I wish to avoid it.

**EDIT1**

Apparently, changing the configSource in code like I did does not automatically refresh the referenced section. I invoked

```
serviceModel.Sections["services"].SectionInformation.GetRawXml()
```

before and after the assignment to the configSource. This explains why my files were overwritten, but still leaves me puzzled how to solve my problem.

Comment: Not that I know of. The only solution is to remove that piece of configuration from the standard config file and move it into a non standard one or database, depending on your needs. Then read it on startup and complete the WCF configuration in code manually.

Comment: Do not have it, because we decided to pursue other more important challenges. We will get to the configuration eventually. Google for it. You will be able to find plenty of samples.